# How to draw an arc?

Tags: java, user-interface

im trying to draw an arc - just a simple looking arc from point (x1,y1) to point (x2,y2)

how do i do that?

i been using the so complex and not freindly to user method called drawArc on Graphics class. no luck yet tho.

thats what i tried:

```
void drawArc(Graphics2D g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
AffineTransform prev = g.getTransform();
    double dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1;
    double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    int len = (int) Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x1, y1);
    at.rotate(angle);
    g.transform(at);
    g.drawArc(len/2, len/2, len ,len/2, 0, 60);
    g.setTransform(prev);
}
```

thanks ahead.

Comment: `"no luck yet tho."` tells us nothing. Please show what you've tried, any error messages, with description of the results obtained vs. results expected, etc... else, how will we know what you're doing wrong?

Comment: You will need to know the radius/curvature too.

Comment: yeah well i dont really mind the radius and curvature, just that the arc will start at (x1,y1) and end at (x2,y2) and would look like an arc, thats all.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels there u go

Comment: OK, now again, please give "any error messages, with a description of the results obtained vs. results expected, etc... "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`graphics.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)` is the simplest possible [arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_%28geometry%29) that you can draw with these information.

Probably it is not what you want. If you want something more ... curvy you need to define somehow how curvy it is, in what direction. The `drawArc` method requires you to calculate an ellipse that touches both points. The arc is the segment of the circle between those points. There is an infinite number of possible ellipses. (The `drawLine` example assumes an infinite ellipse.) But this requires more information (what ellipse to chose) and some calculation.

If you want to draw curves between two points and control points (what you probably want) you need to look into [QuadCurve2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/QuadCurve2D.html) or [CubicCurve2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/CubicCurve2D.html) and `drawShape`. You can find sample code [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html).